# having to reselect the channel everytime I make a change in certain plugins in FL Studio

Tags: midi, fl-studio

I have a problem with FL Studio as whenever I open a VST plugin (both 32 and 64bit) I have to re select it's channel within the step sequencer every time I make a change within the plugin before I am able to send MIDI data to the plugin. it happens only with a certain number of plugins and specially with plugins like massive or bazille.

These are plugins I would like to experiment with but I can't get it to work since I have to select it each time.

I think it has to do with the MIDI keyboard because I installed the driver for it and around the same time it started doing that. I uninstalled the driver for it but it still does that.

Here is a pic of my [MIDI Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwrnR.jpg), I don't know if that is necessary though.

Comment: Have you checked the FL studio forums?

Comment: @ArnoudTraa lost my account and I don't use the same E-mail as i signed up with any more so I can't

Comment: ok... get another email account on gmail perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, this is a common issue with bridged plugins (64bit plugin in 32bit host), but also can happen in normal mode as well. If you are using 32bit / 32bit, try checking the option: "Don't allow keyboard focus", in the channel settings window.

Here are some pics from FL 12 and previous versions (it changes a bit):

https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/img_plug/wrapper_options.jpg

https://support.image-line.com/innovaeditor/assets/KnowledgeBase/Don't%20Allow%20Steal%20Keyboard%20Focus.png

Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to turn it on as default whenever I open the channel?